# Build Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, build

My original post was about one month ago. Looks like Google has really cleaned it up and made the basic features upstream. With the help of Nikolay's comment, I was able to build the contenttest shell and chromium test shell. However the chromium test shell looks exactly like the content shell. It basically has an address bar and back/forward button. That's it.

I am still trying to find my ways in this giant project. But my understanding is that Chromium should be a fully functional browser including the basic UIs such as menus, bookmarks, etc (just like Firefox). Chrome is Google's flavor with their own Google specific services. But Chromium should has the basic features as a fully functional browser. So is it the right understanding? If so, why Android port is not? Anybody knows that if there is the full UI code for Android in Chromium? If not, is it coming or it will be like this going forward? Any other open source project that can be used to add a basic full browser UI to chromium for Android?

Comment: This is as good as it gets: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions. Also note that Chrome is not open source, only Chromium, which is slightly different. And do mention the specific problem you are having, otherwise no one can really help you.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay! I updated my post with new questions. Could you please help to clarify? I am very new to Chromium and your insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: You are on the right track, but I haven't actually built (or used) Chromium on Android, only on Linux, so can't really be of much help. Hopefully someone else will pitch in. Generally, if you ask on the forums/mailing lists you have a better chance of getting answers.

Comment: Thanks! I will post on Google group shortly. So in your experience with Linux, is my understanding that Chromium should come with a fully functional UI correct?

Comment: Yes, Chromium on Linux is fully functional. Maybe the Android one is simply not there yet?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I just posted my question on the Android build page. Hopefully someone will chime in and provide some insight. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/

Comment: @nOiAd I know about zirco, but it is a complete different browser. I still want to use Chrome as the engine. So I was wondering if there is any open source UI based on Chrome, not webview. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Chromium build for Android. As of right now the closest you are going to get is to build the ContentShell described in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions - content shell gives you a lot of the browser that you need, however not all of it.